# Add an eye icon on the password_change_form.html Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to override the `password_change_form.html` Django admin form, most specifically by adding an eye icon on the password section. The eye icon hides and shows the password.

My steps were to first extend the template by creating this file `templates/registration/password_change_form.html` or `PasswordChangeView` class , but I don't exactly know how to override the inputs.

Below is how my form looks :

[image]

The form looks different than the default django one because I changed it's boostraping.

How can I go about this?